# Java BufferedImage changes the RGB that I assign

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that, when selecting an image, reverses the colors of the image.
But when I run the code, my BufferedImage changes the RGB I assigned earlier.
I leave you the code that reverses the image.
image is a static BufferedImage.

```
public static void saveImage(File input, File output) throws IOException{
    image = ImageIO.read(input);
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            boolean isTransparent = isTransparent(x, y);
            if (!isTransparent) {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                int r = 255 - color.getRed();
                int g = 255 - color.getGreen();
                int b = 255 - color.getBlue();
                color = new Color(r, g, b);
                int rgb = color.getRGB();
                image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
                System.out.println(rgb+" --> "+image.getRGB(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
}

public static boolean isTransparent(int x, int y) {
    int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
    return (pixel >> 24) == 0x00;
}
```

Comment: The posted code reverses the colors of the image for me.

Comment: Same as @ProgrammersBlock: works for me, as expected.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will try to check the settings of the IDE.